# I would like to move one picture (i want a part of my document divided in 2 columns)

Tags: two-column

I would like do change my document. One part of it in two columns, because I want to left in left the text and in the right the picture.

I past the picture.
[image]

The code is this one.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item $ \vec{a} + \vec{b} $
\item $ \vec{a} - \vec{b} $
\item $ \vec{b} - \vec{a} $
\item $ 2\vec{a} $
\end{enumerate}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth]
\draw[gray,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(9cm,6cm);
    \draw[ultra thick,red, ->]  (1,4) -- node[above] {\Large $\vec{a}$} +(2,1);
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->]  (7,5) -- node[below left] {\Large $\vec{b}$} +(0,-3);
%%
%    \draw[ultra thick,red, ->]  (4,4) -- node[above] {$\vec{a}$} +(1,0);
%    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->]  (4,4) -- node[below left] {$\vec{b}$} +(1,-2);
%    %
    \draw[ultra thick,black,|-|] (3,1) -- node[below] {\Large $u$} +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Zarko has answered already, but see for example [How can I wrap equations around a TikZ picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207860) and linked questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (at least)  two possibilities to do this:

- put `enumerate` and `tikzpicure` into two succesive minipages
- use `tabular` or `tabularx` environments and put `enumerate` in the first cell and `tikzpicture into second one.

For example:

```
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{3cm}
   \begin{enumerate}
\item $ \vec{a} + \vec{b} $
\item $ \vec{a} - \vec{b} $
\item $ \vec{b} - \vec{a} $
\item $ 2\vec{a} $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{9cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth]
\draw[gray,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(9cm,6cm);
    \draw[ultra thick,red, ->]  (1,4) -- node[above] {\Large $\vec{a}$} +(2,1);
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->]  (7,5) -- node[below left] {\Large $\vec{b}$} +(0,-3);
    \draw[ultra thick,black,|-|] (3,1) -- node[below] {\Large $u$} +(1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Unfortunately the text and the picture are not at a symmetric position.

Comment: @ryuk Try replacing `[t]` with `[c]`.

Comment: What you mind with "symmetric"? With given example in my answer they are top aligned and for `enumerate` is reserved less horisontal width as for `tikzpicture`. If you mind vertical symmetry, than use @TorbjørnT. suggestion.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean that  the two minipage don't start at the same vertical position.

Comment: @Zarko Well, to be precise, the baselines of the top line in each minipage are placed at the same vertical position. The baseline of the `tikzpicture` is at the bottom of the grid, so if you try your example you'll see that the bottom of the grid is at the same height as the baseline of the first point in the list.

Comment: @ryuk If you want the top of the list aligned with the top of the `tikzpicture`, try replacing the `[t]` with `[t][][b]` (for both `minipage`s). Edit: sorry, didn't notice your picture before now, I see that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you. There is only an error

\begin{enumerate} on input line 88 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
Overfull \hbox (85.75827pt too wide) in paragraph

but in the pdf file it's ok! ;)

Comment: sorry I made a mistake! now it's perfect! thanks a lot! :)